# "Genymotion is not configured properly."

Tags: genymotion, nativescript

I am trying to emulate a nativescript android application using Geny but I am getting the following issue:

> Genymotion is not configured properly. Make sure you have added its installation directory to your PATH environment variable.

Nevertheless, I get the following when running "which" from the cli:

```
> which genymotion
/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS//genymotion

> which genyshell
/Applications/Genymotion Shell.app/Contents/MacOS//genyshell
```

My full path looks like this:

```
/usr/local/opt/android-sdk/tools:/usr/local/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools:/usr/local/opt/gradle-2.10/bin:/Applications/Genymotion Shell.app/Contents/MacOS/:/Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

Also, I have no problem running genymotion from the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the version of GenyMotion you have installed (information missing from your question), the geny player changed w/ v 2.6 from being a binary to being an .app bundle.

The actual player binary is now a few layers deeper, in /Applications/Genymotion.app/Contents/MacOS/player.app/Contents/MacOS

See http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/nativescript/running-your-app/run-app-native-emulator for reference.

Comment: Perfect. That was the problem. Also, the extra documentation link is great. Thanks for that too.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a backslash in your PATH - it should be like this:

```
/Applications/Genymotion\ Shell.app/Contents/MacOS/
```

Comment: I am using double quotes, that's why I am not using the backslash for scaping. Besides, that's the "echo $PATH" result.